# ModelService.saveAll method details

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Could anyone please explain ModelService.saveAll and ModelService.save difference. In saveAll array is passed? Please explain below code
ModelService.saveAll([startedWorkOrder.getOwner(), woTimer.getOwner()]).then(function(){

Here woTimer is local resource and startedWorkOrder is actual MBO. So how is data saved in server?

Thanks